# Question about existing addition with pool table settling

Tags: addition

My husband and I bought our house in April. Lovely home built in 2000, and an addition with 2 bedrooms and a bathroom were built over the garage area maybe around 2008. Hardwood floors

When we moved in all the flooring was well done and flush between the addition and the older part of the house upstairs.

One of the addition bedrooms is very long and perfect for a game room so we put a pool table in it. This was just before 4th of July.

Now my office door (other bedroom in the addition) scrapes on the wood in two places and it's getting worse in the last month. The transition between the older and newer parts of the house is lower by about 3-4mm and not flush, and part of the floor next to the pool table has sunk a little bit.

Is this happening because our house settling because of the pool table? My husband thinks we are not in danger, just that the house is settling around the pool table. I am worried that this will cause a crippling amount of damage.

I will also mention that one of the springs broke on our garage door last weekend, and had to be repaired. The addition is over the garage.

Comment: Is the pool table very heavy type, it takes eight or ten muscle guys to move it?  I am guessing the pool table is too heavy for the floor joists and the sag of the joists is causing the movement changes.  Remove the table or beef up the floor joists.

Comment: @crip659  I'd type this up as an answer.

Comment: @JACK  If the pool table is a walmart special, then the problem is someplace else, like the land moving if on a hillside.  A nice solid oak table with a slate top might be the cause or just bad timing getting it.

Comment: I'm hoping the garage joists were either confirmed OK for "living space" loads, or beefed up to account for those.  I'm assuming it was "attic" before the addition, and not all attics are built from the get-go for those loads.  Can you use a laser or level to check the flatness and/or levelness of the garage ceiling?